# Inserting Multiple Rows In A SQLITE Database Using qt

Tags: c++, database, qt, sqlite

Hello I am trying to insert multiple rows (two in this case) into a SQLITE database using qt 5.4. I have been following the documentation but the program has been crashing and I can not explain why.

```
query_Invoice.prepare("INSERT INTO Invoice VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
QVariantList Invoice_Number, Date_Time, Total_Purchased, Qty, Description, Product_CODE, Unit_Price, Total_Price, Goods_Total, VAT_Invoice, Company_ID;
Invoice_Number << 1 << 2;
Date_Time << 1776-07-04 << 1776-07-05;
Total_Purchased << 2 << 3;
Qty << 50 << 60;
Description << "Paint" << "Drill" << QVariant(QVariant::String);
Product_CODE << "EEFF2" << "EEF23" << QVariant(QVariant::String);
Unit_Price << 12 << 13;
Total_Price << 53 << 66;
Goods_Total << 70 << 80;
VAT_Invoice << 55 << 66;
Company_ID << 1 << 2;
query_Invoice.addBindValue(Invoice_Number);
query_Invoice.addBindValue(DateTime);
query_Invoice.addBindValue(Total_Purchased);
query_Invoice.addBindValue(Qty);
query_Invoice.addBindValue(Description);
query_Invoice.addBindValue(Product_CODE);
query_Invoice.addBindValue(Unit_Price);
query_Invoice.addBindValue(Total_Price);
query_Invoice.addBindValue(Goods_Total);
query_Invoice.addBindValue(VAT_Invoice);
query_Invoice.addBindValue(Company_ID);
query_Invoice.execBatch();
qDebug() << query_Invoice.executedQuery();
qDebug() << query_Invoice.lastError();
```

Comment: How have you initialized your database?

Comment: yes, i have connected to the database and have created the table with the corresponding fields

Comment: I see no closing `)` in the query string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by trying to successfully insert one row. You'll need to specify which columns in the table that the values correspond to.

```
query_Invoice.prepare( "INSERT INTO Invoice ( column_name1, column_name2, column_name3 ) VALUES ( ?,?,? )" );
```

Also, `addBindValue( DateTime )` should be `addBindValue( Date_Time )`.

And,

```
query_Invoice.prepare("INSERT INTO Invoice VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"); <---- Closing paren after last '?'
```

Comment: I am abel to insert 1 single row into the database

Comment: Did you try adding the column names?

Comment: Added another suggestion.  DateTime to Date_Time in addBindValue()

Comment: Changed DateTime to Date_Time and it is working, thank you very much for the help.